# How to prove $A \subset B \iff A \cup B = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let A, B be two sets. Prove that $A \subset B \iff A \cup B = B$

I'm thinking of using disjunctive syllogism by showing that $\neg \forall Y(Y \in A).$ However, I'm not sure how the proving steps should proceed such that it leads me to that premise.

Edit: Thanks for the input. FYI, I need to prove this using predicate logic.

Comment: Just take into account that *always* $\,A\subset A\cup B\,$ ...

Comment: Well @uohzxela, now you know...it's important as people volunteering their time and knowledge here want to know both their effort's appreciated and whether their answers are well understood by the OP

Comment: What's disjunctive syllogism (am joking)? To a mathematician, the first question is not "what tool shall I use?" It is "what's happening here?"  So one draws a picture. Then the picture guides one to a proof.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taking the "longer" road. Let us review the definitions:

1. $A\subseteq B$ if and only if *for every $x\in A$, $x\in B$*.
2. $x\in A\cup B$ if and only if $x\in A$ **or** $x\in B$.
3. $A=B$ if and only if $A\subseteq B$ **and** $B\subseteq A$.
4. $P\iff Q$ means that if we assume that $P$ holds, then $Q$ must hold; and vice versa.

---

Now assume $A\subseteq B$. This means that for every $x\in A$ we have $x\in B$. We want to show that $A\cup B=B$.

- So we take $x\in B$, then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, and therefore $x\in A\cup B$.
- Now take $x\in A\cup B$, we want to show that $x\in B$. By definition either $x\in A$ or $x\in B$.

  - If $x\in B$ we are done.
  - If $x\in A$ then by the assumption that $A\subseteq B$ we have that $x\in B$.

  Either way we have that $x\in B$.

We have shown that **if** $A\subseteq B$ **then** $A\cup B\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A\cup B$, which is by fact number $3$ to say $A\cup B=B$.

---

Now we need to assume that $A\cup B=B$, and deduce that $A\subseteq B$. So we need to show that if $x\in A$ *then* $x\in B$.

Take $x\in A$ to be an arbitrary element. Because $x\in A$ we have that $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, and therefore $x\in A\cup B$. The assumption was, however, that $A\cup B=B$ and therefore we have that $x\in B$ as wanted.

Comment: Your answer is very comprehensive and well-explained. Thank you.

Comment: In your last sentence, assuming that A is contained in B, then you take an arbitrary element of A, why you say that "X belongs to A OR X belongs to B". Shouldn't it be an AND? Because A is assumed to be contained in B. Please explain, I'm learning

Answer (score 8):

Let $A\subset B$. Since $B\subset B$, we have $A\cup B\subset B$. Clearly, $B\subset A\cup B$. Hence $A\cup B=B$.

Let $A\not\subset B$. Then there is some $x\in A$ with $x\not\in B$. Clearly, $x\in A\cup B$. Hence $A\cup B\neq B$.

Comment: Good Will Hunting, good!

Comment: Short and sweet! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here are the (very straightforward) first steps you should have thought of beginning with:

In one direction, suppose $A\subseteq B$: then $A\cup B\subseteq B\cup B\dots$

In the other direction, suppose $A\cup B=B$: then $A\subseteq A\cup B\subseteq\dots$

Answer (score 1):

For the first implication a draw can help us: 
[image]

and now it is obvious.

Now conversely, we have:

$A \cup B =B \Rightarrow$ $A \cup B \subset B \tag{1}$ and $B \subset A \cup B\tag{2}.$ We need only the relation $(1)$ which help us to conclude that: $A \subset B.$

Answer (score -1):

Let  $A\subseteq B$.
**Claim:** We need to prove $A\cup B\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A\cup B$

Let  $x\in A\cup B$. Then  $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. But $A\subseteq B$. Hence $x\in B$. Therefore $A\cup B\subseteq B$.

Now conversely $x\in B$. Then $x\in A\cup B$. Therefore $B\subseteq A\cup B$. Thus $A\cup B=B$.

Consider $A\cup B=B$. 
**Claim:** $A\subseteq B$
Let $x\in A$. Then  $x\in A\cup B=B$. Therefore $A\subseteq B$.