# $(A=A\cup B )\Leftrightarrow B\subset A$ - is it true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find out whether the following statement is true:

$(A=A\cup B )\Leftrightarrow B\subset A$

In my opinion it is, because $A=A\cup B$ if B is either an empty set, or $A=B$ or $B \subset A$, all of which are are equivalent with $B \subset A$.

Could you please verify my proof?

Thanks

Comment: This is such an obvious result, that I think you are expected to be careful with your proof. You have to establish both implications. (1) If $A=A\cup B$, then any element in $A\cup B$ is in $A$. Since any element in $B$ is in $A\cup B$, that implies that any element in $B$ is in $A$, in other words that $B\subseteq A$. (2) For the converse, suppose that $B\subseteq A$. Then any element in $B$ is in $A$. But any element in $A\cup B$ is either in $A$ or in $B$. Hence in either case, it is in $A$, so $A\cup B\subseteq A$. But by definition $A\subseteq A\cup B$, so $A=A\cup B$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194218/how-to-prove-a-subset-b-iff-a-cup-b-b

Comment: You are correct and you are probably correct for the right reasoning but your explanation is vague. $B=\emptyset$ and $B=A$ are not "equivalent" to $B\subset A$.  They "imply" that $B\subset A$ is true. But those are not the only three options. There's also $A\subset B$ and $A$ and $B$ having elements in common or $A$ and $B$ having elements the other dont, etc.  As a "proof" I actually fail to see any argument. You seem to say it because you say it.

Comment: You are proving one way and not the other and your proof makes assumptions without verification.  If $A=A\cup B$ you say that means either $B=\emptyset, B=A$ or $B\subset A$.  Why? Why must one of those three be true? Better to say.  If $A=A\cup B$ then if $x\in B$ then it is true that $x\in A\cup B$ as $A\cup B$ is the set of all elements in $B$ as well as in $A$. But $A\cup B=A$ so $x\in A$ so $B\cup A$. Then prove the other direction as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B \subset A$, then $A\cup B = A$. Indeed, $A \subset A\cup B \subset A\cup A = A$. Reciprocally, suppose $A = A\cup B$ and let us prove that $B \subset A$. If this was *not* the case, then there would be an $x \in B$ such that $x \not\in A$. But because $x \in B$, we obviously have $x \in A\cup B$, so that it cannot be $A = A\cup B$ (since the left side does not have $x$ and the right side does).

Answer (score 2):

$$B\not\subseteq A\iff \exists x\in B\setminus A\iff x\in A\cup B, x\notin A \iff A\neq A\cup B$$

Comment: Not sure I understand.

Comment: @LukasT Is this better?

Comment: So you did proof by contradiction?

Comment: No, by contrapositive

Comment: [Contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition)